# iPad app & Mac app, how to do promotion with applications on different platform?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

I already post a question regarding if it was possible to make iPad app free for users buying a Mac app, via apple store.  I got an answer that it might be possible via promo code, in the following scenario

1. The user buy the iPad app
2. A promotion code is generated for him,
3. User goes to buy the Mac app, he enters the promo code so he get a discount for the Mac app

Question 1 :

- Does this scenario is possible?

Question 2 :

- If yes, the promotion code generated when user buys the iPad app, is it a unique promotion code?  Or he will be able to give the promotion code to his friends, and these friends will get the discount on the Mac app too?

Finally, the following scenario is the preferred scenario:

1. The users buy the Mac app via app store
2. A promotion code is generated for him
3. Users goes on iPad app store, to get the iPad application.  He enters the promo code, and he gets the iPad application for free
4. *(Users not buying the Mac application have to pay for the iPad application)*

Question 3:

- Does this preferred scenario is possible?

Question 4:

- *Same as question number 2*

Question 5:

- Anybody have a better idea how to do promotion like this?  (*Buy Mac app and get iPad app for free etc...*)

Thank you very much!

Comment: "He enters the promo code, and he gets the iPad application for free" - This is possible I think. I recently read a magazine that sent you a promo code via email for a free iTunes album and because it's the same payment system I'm pretty sure this is possible. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

A Developer has to request the promo codes ahead of time, and the number is limited (currently 50 max) for each app version.  There may also be other restrictions in the click-thru agreement required to get any promo codes.